# NSURLConnection NSMutableURLRequest and HTTPS

Tags: https, nsurlconnection

I have the following code which uploads an image to a web site.

```
[request setURL:nsurl];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];  

NSString *boundary = [NSString stringWithString:@"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449"];  
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];  
[request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];  

/* 
 now lets create the body of the post 
 */  
NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];  

//parameter1  
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];   
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"guid\"\r\n\r\n%@", [Settings sharedInstance].uploadID] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];  
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];  
//Image  
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"filMyFile\"; filename=\"%@\"\r\n", fileName] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];  
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: image/png\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];  
[body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:dataObj]];  
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];  

// setting the body of the post to the reqeust  
[request setHTTPBody:body];  

NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

All is well when running over HTTP, but when I switch to HTTPS it fails with

Error: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1005 "The network connection was lost." UserInfo=0x1c7f70 {NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https:.......

The server it is communicating with is MS Server 2008 R2.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Neil.

Comment: Also, the server is running IIS with ASP.Net 4.

Answer (score 0):

Refer Using NSURLConnection for https connection
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html